# Does simplepie $itme->get_content() output need to be escaped when echoing to page?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, escaping, simplepie

I have a WordPress plugin that reads an RSS feed and outputs it to the browser in an admin page. In the plugin, it uses the standard feed.php template from WordPress (wp-includes/feed.php), which uses SimplePie to fetch the feed through WordPress.

The page loops through the feed items and uses `$item->get_title()` and `$item->get_content()` to output the item title and content via a direct echo to the page.

I have had a user contact me to tell me that they had a security audit done on their site and it failed because we used the `$item->get_content()` and are not escaping it before output to the browser and that this is an XSS vulnerability because HTML is being read from a vendor's website and needs to be escaped.

**Is this correct?**

In all the documentation for using the `get_content()` function, they show echoing out the `$item->get_content()` results.

Can someone shed light on this so I can best address this either with the security audit team and/or user - or update the plugin correctly if it needs to be escaped.

Thanks!
Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audit is wrong. SimlePie ***does*** escape the content internally. If you look into the SimplePie class source you will see this property that define the tags that will be stripped:

```
public $strip_htmltags = array('base', 'blink', 'body', 'doctype', 'embed', 'font', 'form', 'frame', 'frameset', 'html', 'iframe', 'input', 'marquee', 'meta', 'noscript', 'object', 'param', 'script', 'style');
```

So `<script>` tags are stripped out - so no XSS attack can be done.

This is the default behaviour of SimplePie, so except if you intentionally tell it to run in fast mode by calling: `$feed->set_stupidly_fast(true)` (as you see the function name speak for itself :) ) or by calling `$feed->strip_htmltags(true)` ; it will run in safe mode.

From the SimplePie documentation:

> SimplePie protects against malicious feeds by sanitizing the data.

Comment: Thanks vard - that is what I thought, but had to be sure.